# Using Angular Observers to fetch data over a network

Tags: json, angular, rxjs, angular2-http

I'm working on an Angular app that contains a list of (financial) Trades that a user can add to. This has been going well, and I'm trying to switch over from a static list provided by a service to trying to fetch the data from a local Node.js server. I'm using an observer to asynchronously fetch the list of trades.

I've been following along with Angular's [HTTP tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/http) and the associated [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview). However, even though I can see the data coming from the server, I'm having trouble using the .subscribe() method to get a useful set of data out of it.

**Here's my service which connects to the node server:**

```
   @Injectable()
export class TradeService {
  private url = '...';  // URL to web API
  tradeArray: Trade[] = [];
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  //-----------GETTERS---------------//
  getTradeObservable(): Observable<Trade> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    console.log("body:" + body);
    console.log("Entire Body.trades: " + body.trades);
    return body.trades;
  }

  getTrades(): any {
    this.getTradeObservable()
      .subscribe(
          trade => this.tradeArray.push(trade));
    return this.tradeArray;
  }
```

**And here are the relevant portions the node server itself:**

```
var TRADES = { "trades": [
   {"id": 0, "cust": "Ben", "hasSub": true,
       "subcust": "Rigby", "type": "s", "security": "001", "ticket": "99"},
   ...
   {"id": 9, "cust": "Uber Bank", "hasSub": true,
            "subcust": "Lil Bank", "type": "p", "security": "456", "ticket": "56"}
]};


////////////Get Requests/////////////////

//this route returns all data in JSON format
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send(JSON.stringify(TRADES));
    });
```

**And the expected output from getTrades:**

```
[
   {id: 0, cust: "Ben", hasSub: true,
       subCust: "Rigby", type: "s", security: '001', ticket: '99'},
   ...
   {id: 9, cust: "Uber Bank", hasSub: true,
            subCust: "Lil' Bank", type: "p", security: '456', ticket: '56'},
];
```

**And one of the places the service is injected into and called:**

```
export class SubmittedComponent {
  constructor(private tradeService: TradeService) { }

  //initally show all trades
  rows = this.tradeService.getTrades();
...
```

I can see in the browser console that 'entire body.trades' is a full list of the data I want, but it seems subscribe is not pushing them into tradeArray, which ends up undefined.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you post the component from which you call the service? Btw, its a bad practice to subscribe inside of your services. Your service should only return observables

Comment: I've updated the post. Thanks for the tip on subscribers, I will look into that.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo you can absolutely subscribe within the service but still expose an observable, I wrote about it here: http://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html

Comment: Yeah but in that case you are using a Subject, which is another topic. Nice article, maybe could help OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I suppose that you are calling getTrades() from one of your components. If this is the case, this is what will happen:

- The request will be sent
- The request will be processed in the background asynchronously
- The method will not wait for the request to be resolved and will return the current value of tradeArray, which is []

To avoid this, you could refactor you components so that they invoke the `getTradeObservable()` method an subscribe to the returned `Observable`.

UPDATE: Another option would be to refactor you service to use a `Subject', and expose it to your components through an`Observable`.

UPDATE: Assuming that you have the following definition for Trade

```
export interface Trade{
   id: number;
   cust: string;
   hasSub: boolean;
   subCust: string;
   type: string;s
   security: string;
   ticket: string;
}
```

You could try the following approach

```
class TestComponent {
  data: Trade[];
  // inject service in component

  getData(){
     this.service.getTradesObservable().subscribe(data => this.data = data);
  }
}
```

And change the definition of getTradesObservable to :

```
getTradeObservable(): Observable<Trade[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. However, I've noticed that tradeArray does not seem to be populating ever, possibly suggesting there is another problem. I tried giving the task time to complete: `setTimeout(function() {console.log("Test:" + this.tradeArray);}, 5000);` and even after 5 seconds the array was undefined.

Comment: Is Trade defined as an array or a singular element? It just called my attention that you try to push the traders property of the server response, which is an array,

Comment: Trade is a defined class making up the tradeArray. It has the same properties as the expected output and server-supplied json -- I was intending to push each Trade from the response onto the tradeArray individually.

Comment: This was it. Thank you for your help. I'll add a cleaned up version to the post once I've corrected the bad practices.

Comment: Another tip:: http requests will always return POJOs. You can only map them to classes by calling the constructor method of the class. For this reason if better to just define the return types of your service methods through interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Speaking just about this portion of the code:

```
getTrades(): any {
    this.getTradeObservable()
      .subscribe(
          trade => this.tradeArray.push(trade));
    return this.tradeArray;
  }
```

since `getTradeObservable` is asynchronous this line: `return this.tradeArray;` will (maybe) execute before the observable is resolved, you should remove `getTrades` method from your service and instead get a hold of the observable returned by `getTradeObservable` in your component and rather than expecting the whole thing to return the value you want, you should assign that value in the subscription like this:

```
    @Component({
       providers:[TradeService ]
    })
    export class myComponent{
        trades:Trade[];
    constructor(tradeService:TradeService){
        tradeService.getTradeObservable().subscribe(tradeRes=>this.trades=tradeRes as Trade[]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip -- I'll make this change and post a cleaned up version with the correct subscriber usage.